# Let A $n*n$ nonsingular, B $n*n$. Show that if $||BA^{-1}||<1$, then A+B nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A be a $n*n$ nonsingular matrix,
and B a $n*n$ matrix.
Let ||.|| be an induced matrix norm.

In the lecturenotes of a course that I'm taking (roughly) the following statements are made:

'If $||BA^{-1}||<1$, then B+A nonsingular,
because $\rho (BA^{-1}) \leq ||BA^{-1}||$,
we find $\rho (BA^{-1}) < 1$, so B+A nonsingular.'
(Where $\rho (BA^{-1})$ is the spectral radius of $BA^{-1}$, i.e. the largest of the absolute values of eigenvalues of $BA^{-1}$)

It is unclear to me why $\rho (BA^{-1}) \leq ||BA^{-1}||$,
and why $\rho (BA^{-1}) < 1$ leads to B+A nonsingular.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(I+BA^{-1})(x)=0$ implies that $BA^{-1}(x)=-x$. Impossible if $x\neq 0$ since $\|BA^{-1}\|<1$. Thus $I+BA^{-1}$ is invertible, since $A$ is invertible, $(I+BA^{-1})A=A+B$ is invertible.

Comment: Hi, Tsemo. Thanks for your fast reply, and sorry for my slow reply. Could you please elaborate more on the following: 'Impossible if x≠0 since $||BA^{-1}||<1$. Thus $I+BA^{-1}$ is invertible'? How does that follow from the matrix norm of $||BA^{-1}||$?

Comment: Oh, actually: $(I+BA^{−1})(x)=0$ implies that  $BA^{−1}(x)=−x$, so $\frac{||BA^{−1}(x)||}{||x||}=1$, but $max \frac{||BA^{−1}(x)||}{||x||} = ||BA^{-1}|| < 1$. So $(I+BA^{−1})(x)=0$ holds only if $x=0$, so $(I+BA^{−1})$ is invertible.

Comment: I think I get it, thank you very much :)